# Can i Use Google Maps Static API for getting "my maps"?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently came across the Google Maps Static API, Which helped me add a snapshot of any specified location as an image in my application.

But I wanted to know if I can take the snapshot of "My maps" (a customized map view in Google maps application) by querying static maps API.

[Customized MyMaps Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6j7M.png)

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: I actually need exactly that, I've been searching everywhere still no answer. this is called tile overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible as long as you use Google Maps style in here. You can see in the Feature Parameters in the [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Overview), there is a style parameter here stated that it defines a custom style to alter the presentation of a specific feature (road, park, etc.) of the map. This parameter takes feature and element arguments identifying the features to select and a set of style operations to apply to that selection. You may supply multiple styles by adding additional style parameters.

For more information about Styled Maps, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#StyledMaps).

Comment: Thank you so much. But it seems like I need to format it using my query every time. I was looking for something like I design the map once using google's "my maps tool" and use the query to get the snapshot of that map for my current location. Thanks anyways, it helped a lot,